# my C solution to a multiplicity issue is too slow, need suggestions

Tags: c, algorithm

I am looking to make this much more efficient. It's taking a very long time to execute this simple program.

Are there any suggestions you could make to make it run faster? I am not sure what I am doing wrong to make this so slow.

FYI this is just a practice problem to work on my coding skills.. help is appreciated. It's written in C.

PROBLEM: 
compute the sum of multiples of 3 and 5 which are less than 1000.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sumOfFivesAndThrees( int start, int limit ){
    int sum = start;
    int idx = 0;

    printf("Your input is:  %i\n", start);

    while( idx <= limit ) { 
        if( ! idx % 3 ){
            sum = sum + idx;
            printf("IDX(3): %i\n", idx);
        }
        else if( ! idx % 5 ){
            sum = sum + idx;
            printf("IDX(5): %i\n", idx);
        }
        idx++;      
    }

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int answer = 0;

    answer = sumOfFivesAndThrees( answer, 1000 );

    printf("Your of 3's and 5's is:  %i\n", answer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [You might want to ask on CodeReview instead](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The `printf` statements will be slowing it down a great deal.

Comment: Not knowing what the problem you're trying to solve actually *is* doesn't help much either. it isn't clear you know what the expression `!idx % n`  actually *does* (as opposed to `!(idx % n)` ) .  Logical-not of a counter that will only be 0 (and thus the expression "true" *once*), then taken modulo `3`  seems odd.

Comment: what are u trying to do?

Comment: You may **compute** directly the result without brute-force. **Hint**: See [Arithmetic_progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).

Comment: Second hint :15 is the Least_common_multiple of 3 and 5.

Comment: @Jarod42 This is an exercise for programming skills, not just trying to calculate the answer.

Comment: which platform (Intel/ARM/Some DSP ...) are you working on?

Comment: `idx % 3` and `sum % 5`, really?

Comment: @Barmar: Using the correct algorithm is part of programming. Not taking an `O(1)` versus `O(N)` would be an error for me.

Comment: @Jarod42 If you're trying to learn about looping, it won't do you any good to use the formula for the sum of an arithmetic progression instead of writing a loop that accumulates it.

Comment: This problem can be found on Hackerrank Project Euler. To solve this you should used the solution proposed by @Jarod42. I understand that you want to practice your coding skills, but you should use the proper problem (This problem will never get accepted with a linear complexity).

Answer (score 4):

A faster solution is to use [Arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression):

```
int sumOfMultipleOfX(int minRange, int maxRange, int mul)
{
    minRange = ((minRange + mul - 1) / mul) * mul; // Ceil to multiple
    maxRange = (maxRange / mul) * mul;             // Floor to multiple

    if (maxRange < minRange) { // Check input arguments.
        return 0;
    }
    return (maxRange + minRange) * (maxRange - minRange + mul) / (2 * mul);
}

int sumOfMultipleOf3Or5(int minRange, int maxRange)
{
    return sumOfMultipleOfX(minRange, maxRange, 3)
        + sumOfMultipleOfX(minRange, maxRange, 5)
        - sumOfMultipleOfX(minRange, maxRange, 15); // Count multiple of 15 only once
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/jqX9GU)

Answer (score 2):

Follow following steps

- Initialize idx by 3. Increase idx by 3 till limit. Add all idx to the sum.
- Initialize idx by 5. Increase idx by 5 till limit. Add all idx to the sum.
- Initialize idx by 15. Increase idx by 15 till limit. Subtract all idx from the sum.

Comment: So that the sequence will be 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, right?

Comment: Thanks Jarod42. Sorry my mistake. I have update my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Please avoid % operation. from start check the first divisible by 3 number then increment by 3 and add all to sum till limit. then check the first divisible by 5 number then increment by 5 and add all to previous sum till limit

Comment: Second time we should leave divisible by 3 numbers

Answer (score 1):

You should set sum = 0 instead of sum = start;